# Finding minima and maxima of function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to find local minima and maxima of the funtion and I am struggling . We can see that it should have 1 minima and 4 maxima but I am doing something wrong and I dont know how to continue.

Thanks for help!

```
 %1
figure;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-3:0.01 : 3 );
z=x.*sin(x)+y.*sin(y);
mesh(x,y,z);
xlabel("x");
ylabel("y");
zlabel("z");
title(" Graph  f(x,y) = x*sin(x)+y*sin(y)");

%2 trying to find minima and maxima of funtion
fun=@(x)x(1).*sin(x(1))+x(2).*sin(x(2));

x0 = [-1,-1];
[x,fval,exitflag,output]=fminsearch(fun,x0);
%locmax=findpeaks(z);

%mask = imregionalmax(z);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good for finding the minima.  When I run it I find the minima near [0, 0] (with a accuracy of `~1e-4`).  For finding the maxima you probably want to invert your function

```
x0 = [-1, -1];
fun=@(x) -x(1).*sin(x(1))-x(2).*sin(x(2));
[x,fval,exitflag,output]=fminsearch(fun,x0)
```

With this modified function and starting condition I find the maxima at `[-2, -2]`:

```
x =

   -2.0287   -2.0288


fval =

   -3.6394


exitflag =

     1
```

For `fminsearch` you will need to provide multiple starting guesses if you want to find all your local minima and maxima.  Try `[1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]`.

Comment: "...Try [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1] " why do I need all this combinations?  I mean If I plot a graph I see that it has 1 local minima and 4 local maxima. Is it neccessary to be to precise? Anyways thanks for help.

Comment: @BlackSwan_22: `fminsearch` finds one local minimum at the time, and which one it finds depends on initialization. You can use the output of `findpeaks(z)` to find good start points.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes , I understand.. I did it for all combinations [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1] for maxima and minima.